# AWS EC2 ssh connection with key pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am beginning using AWS. Previously, I have created AWS "Amazon AMI" type instance. I could connect using putty without an issue using a key-pair I have created before hand.

I am now trying to do the same using a "Ubuntu AMI". However, proceeding the exact same way, putty throws me "the server refused our key" error.

I thought I understand key-pair is not AMI-specific. What could be wrong then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key pair is not AMI specific. But the AMI is key specific.

This means that you can create "n" no. of instances with "n" key-pairs.

Also you can use a single key-pair for all "n" instances but you need to select that at the booting time.

Also the username is AMI specific i.e

ubuntu for all ubuntu

ec2-user for all RHEL.

Please check the AMI specific username for the newly created AMI

Comment: Spot on. I did not see that the username changed between AMI. Thanks !